# Enable php curl in gentoo linux

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, gentoo

I've PHP installed in server (gentoo linux) without curl support. I know how to add php curl extension in ubuntu, centos, etc. But I'm new to gentoo.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Habeeb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should emerge PHP with the curl USE flag. I'm going to assume you know more or less what emerge and an USE flag is, since you've stated you've installed PHP already.

You should add this line to `/etc/portage/package.use`:

```
dev-lang/php curl
```

And then emerge php telling Portage to look for new USE flags:

```
emerge --newuse dev-lang/php
```

Keep in mind that both editing package.use and emerge need to be done as a super user.

Comment: In my case it wasn't sufficient to emerge php on top of the previous installation and `php -i | grep --color curl` was still showing it being compiled with `--without-curl`. I had to `emerge --ask --verbose --depclean dev-lang/php` and then `emerge --newuse dev-lang/php`